# how to get from Hive to HiveServer2 in UBUNTU

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, hadoop, hive, ubuntu-14.04

I followed 1 guide and was able to setup, hadoop and hive on my virtual machine ubuntu. Now, i want to get hiveserver2 to start in ubuntu. I am not able to find any guide which will tell me how to get started with hiveserver2.

my plan is to get hiveserver2 then beeline and mysql, later connect to mysql in HDFS to tomcat and use eclipse to develop some DB software.

I am **not** expecting big answers from anyone, just some references to study from.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could try the documentation for hive provided by Cloudera.
[Cloudera Installation Guide](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-3-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_hive_metastore_configure.html)